# Left and right tracks of audio cancel or mute each other

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audacity

I had some some video files that seemed muted on my video player box. On my laptop, the audio plays fine out of the built-in speakers but not from headphone jack.

Using ffmpeg, I extracted the audio stream as an MP3 file and examined it in Audacity. The MP3 file has identical left and right tracks. If I press the solo button on the left or right track, I hear the audio in the headphone jack.

The left and right channels seem to cancel each other if they get mixed and then sent to a speaker. If each channel is directly output to a speaker, there is no problem.

Currently, I am making these audio tracks to mono but is there some other way to fix it. I would like to know what is causing the tracks to cancel each other.

Update 1: I checked the waveform in Audacity and the left and right tracks are vertically flipped. The original file got deleted. I could not [download it](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7jdzne) again soon enough.

[Audacity waveform showing left and right tracks flipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCYP9.png)

Comment: To elaborate on @Slartibartfast's answer, you're essentially listening to an active noise-cancellation track, as active noise-canceling speakers create a 180-degree out-of-phase wave that's the inverted opposite of the wave of intrusive sound.  All you need to do is flip the out-of-phase channel so it's in-phase _(swapping pos and neg wires on the speaker also does the same)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the phase of the stereo tracks is such that they cancel themselves out, you can try reversing the phase of one of the tracks using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af "aeval=val(0)|-val(1)" out.wav
```

Here, `aeval` creates a stereo track with the left channel being the same as the left channel input (`val(0)`) and the right channel being the *inverted* value of the right channel input (`-val(1)`).

Comment: My old ffmpeg does not support aeval but aevalsrc is available. The filter documentation says this is how the phase has to be changed so I think this answer is correct. It might be useful to someone else. As I am unable to upgrade ffmpeg, my solution is to remove one channel and make it mono.

On my speaker, I have added a pushbutton to mute one of the channels before it goes to the amplifier circuit.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade? Can you run a static build (see http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)? These don't require installation and are always up-to-date.

Comment: The Ubuntu OS is very old. Libc v2 library cannot be upgraded. I will upgrade the OS next year. I builld from source.

Comment: how would you do that using `pulse-audio` ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a neat problem!

My guess (not even 100% sure how to check,though possibly Audacity) is that the left and right channels are 180 degrees out of phase with each other, meaning when the value of one is at 3.4, the other is at -3.4.  You don't hear this, because what you typically hear is the change in values, and because that change happens in both the positive and negative directions (yay waves!), a sound and one that is phase shifted do not sound different.

However, if those values are mixed together naively (e.g. adding, and then dividing by two), you will get (3.4 + -3.4) / 2, which is the same as 0/2, which is functionally 0.

I suspect you can confirm this by separating the original audio into left and right channels in Audacity, and zooming in to the point where you can see individual samples.  It should look vaguely like:

```
left:  /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
right: \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
```

Comment: This is the case in Audacity.  slhck probably has the solution.